# Bat file to search ini file and copy from network to pc

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have no programing skills and i need some help.

I have to connect to a lot of computer and look in a certain ini file for a setting. Since i have to look trough more than 1000 pc this job would require a lot of time to complet.
I would need some help in creating a batch file to help me in my job.

The batch should search trough the network pc in a certain folder (ex: \172.16.35.100\c$) for a file (Displayer.ini) and copy it to my pc with a diferrent name like the IP adress of the PC and name (172.16.35.100_Displayer.ini)

It shouldn't be more than a few lines (I have no ideea and hope it's not hard) I would just replicate this small script to contain all the pc's in my list to get the data in my PC and then look trough the ini files later.

The script should work like this:
We can use a example list
search in **\172.29.35.132\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.132_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.133\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.133_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.136\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.136_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.137\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.137_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.138\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.138_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.141\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.141_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.142\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.142_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.143\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.143_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.146\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.146_Displayer.ini**
search in **\172.29.35.147\c$** for **Displayer.ini** copy the found file **Displayer.ini** to **D:\Search** with name something like **172.29.35.147_Displayer.ini**

At the end of the script i should have 10 files in my **D:Search** folder

Comment: How are you going to get the list of PC's? Are you in an AD environment or *nix? Edit your answer and show the contents of one of the INI files.

Comment: The list of PC is in a Excel file all filled with IP adresses.
Yes I am in a AD env

Comment: Ok. start by extracting the IP's into a .txt file so we can easily process them. The reason I asked if you're in an AD environment is because I have already written code to loop through all PC's in AD or a specific OU. But you already have them in a SS so it's easier to just extract to a txt file and read them from it.

Comment: It's better to edit your answer so you can format the info you put in your comment. I still need to see the contents of one of the INI files to be able to really help though.

Comment: I eddited the info so you might understand a little of what i would want.

Comment: Did you understand my request? Hope the explination is understandable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

For /f "delims=" %%a in (comps.txt) do (
   pushd "%%a\c$"
   if /i exist Displayer.ini copy Displayer.ini "\\yourpc\d$\Search\%%a_Displayer.ini"
   popd
)
```